# Saving Doubles from text file for later use C++

Tags: c++, arrays, input, double

I want to read 3 doubles from a text file that has 3 doubles per line(number of lines is not sure beforehand). Then either save these doubles into 3 different arrays to use the doubles later. Or to read the program 1 line at a time, save the line it was on, use the 3 doubles I need and then go to the next line to use the next 3 doubles.

Which method would be better for using/saving these doubles?

If the array is a better way for saving them, how can I make an array that counts the lines of the file to know how many elements it should have and save the values in the right array while reading in the file?

My file reading code looks like this so far

```
ifstream theFile("pose.txt");
double first,second,third;
while(theFile >> first >> second >> third){
    cout<<first<<" " << second <<" "<< third<<endl;
    /*some code here to save values in different arrays for
     use later or use the 3 values straight away while keeping the line
     number and then moving on to the next line to use those values
     straight away*/
}
```

Any help with code or suggestions for my logic on the problem is welcome,

Thanks.

EDIT: Firstly I'm not sure if my logic of saving the values into an array is correct design wise and secondly I'm not sure how to add these three values into different arrays within the loop.

Comment: Was there a problem...?

Comment: Check the edit I've made my problem more clear.

Comment: You don't have an array and your question is still unclear. Check out the help center for what sort of questions you should ask here.

Comment: The key point being that they should be _questions_.

Comment: Is it more clear now..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vector of struct might help:

```
struct Values {
    double first;
    double second;
    double third;
};

std::vector<Values> v;

while(theFile >> first >> second >> third){
    cout<<first<<" " << second <<" "<< third<<endl;
    Values values;
    values.first = first;
    values.second = second;
    values.third = third;
    v.push_back(values);
}
```

To relate that with a line number, you can also use a map

```
std::map<int,Values> m;
int lineno = 1;
while(theFile >> first >> second >> third){
    cout<<first<<" " << second <<" "<< third<<endl;
    Values values;
    values.first = first;
    values.second = second;
    values.third = third;
    v[lineno++] = values;
}
```

Comment: If I use the struct way how will i then call the values of the first row for instance for use, then the second etc.?

Comment: You can simply use `v[1].first`, `v[2].first`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using stringstreams (`#include <sstream>`) should be helpful.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        stringstream str(line); //declare a stringstream which is initialized to line
        double a,b,c;
        str >> a >> b >> c ;
        cout << "A is "<< a << " B is "<< b << " C is " << c <<endl; 
    }
}
```